# Hide part of match from grep output

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have a regex for session ID extraction:

```
[root@docker tmp]# grep -oE "\[[0-9].+\]" logfile
[113a6d9e-7b06-42c6-a52b-7a4e4d2e216c]
[113a6d9e-7b06-42c6-a52b-7a4e4d2e216c]
[root@docker tmp]#
```

How can I hide the square brackets from the output?

Comment: can you post the contents of your logfile. may be you need awk command to process and get the desired output

Comment: @Kamaraj , Thank you for responding. awk is in my mind. But I am trying to solve this with only grep+regex.

Comment: can you post the contents of log file.. atleast 2 lines

Comment: Second you can pipe output trough `| tr -d ']['` e.g.

Comment: maybe this will work : grep -oE "\[[0-9].+\]" logifle | awk -F"[][]" '{print $2}'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using extended-regex grep (`-E`), use perl-regex grep instead (`-P`), with a lookbehind and lookahead.

```
$ grep -oP "(?<=\[)[0-9].+(?=\])" logfile
113a6d9e-7b06-42c6-a52b-7a4e4d2e216c
113a6d9e-7b06-42c6-a52b-7a4e4d2e216c
```

Here, `(?<=\[)` indicates that there should be a preceding `\[`, and `(?=\])` indicates that there should be a following `\]`, but not to include them in the match output.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat a.txt
test hello..[113a6d9e-7b06-42c6-a52b-7a4e4d2e216c]... this is
te [113a6d9e-7b06-42c6-a52b-7a4e4d2e216c].  this  is hello

$ grep -oP '(?<=\[)[^\]]*' a.txt
113a6d9e-7b06-42c6-a52b-7a4e4d2e216c
113a6d9e-7b06-42c6-a52b-7a4e4d2e216c
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19242713/6947646

Answer (score 2):

**sed** is more applicable for the case than **grep**

```
sed '/\n/{P;D;};s/\[/\n/;s/\]/\n/;D' log
```

Comment: Hey, could you please explain what sed doing here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One way is piping to `cut`:

```
grep -oE "\[[0-9].+\]" logfile | cut -d'[' -f2 | cut -d']' -f1
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to let `tr` delete them:

```
$ grep -oE "\[[0-9].+\]" logfile | tr -d '[]'
113a6d9e-7b06-42c6-a52b-7a4e4d2e216c
113a6d9e-7b06-42c6-a52b-7a4e4d2e216c
```

Notice that the `tr` utility doesn't know about regular expressions or patterns in quite the same way as the shell does. In this case, the `[]` operand is just the two characters `[` and `]`.

Comment: Yes , i tried that as well and same answer already posted as comment by @Costas